# More than one selected part in YouTube video

Tags: youtube

I know that I can attach `start=XXX;end=YYY;` to YouTube URL to play back only specific part of it. But, what if I want to play another selection right after the first one? Concatenating `start=X1;end=Y1;start=X2;end=Y2;` failed in my experiment. Can you provide a working solution?